# Laravel 5.5 How to use Foreach loop in LaravelCollective Forms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to to use foreach loop in select form. But I dont figure out how can I do that.

I searched about it in here, in other questions and found lists method. But when I tried it retuns me  "Call to undefined method App\Category::lists()" error.

```
{{ Form::select('categories',

"foreach loop" for bringing categories

) }}
```

Any advice ?

Comment: Did you send the categories as collection from Controller ??

Comment: @Maraboc , I just send categories data ( $categories = Category::all();
        return view('back.create')->withCategories($categories);)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discribed in the [Laravel Recipes](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field) :

If you use this :

```
{{ Form::select('age', ['Under 18', '19 to 30', 'Over 30']) }}
```

You will get this output :

```
<select name="age">
  <option value="0">Under 18</option>
  <option value="1">19 to 30</option>
  <option value="2">Over 30</option>
</select>
```

So in your case you can use it like this :

```
{{ Form::select('categories', $categories->pluck('name')) }}
```

If you want to addthe id of the category as value of the option you can do it like this :

In the controller :

```
$categories = [''=>''] + Category::lists('name', 'id')->all();
return view('back.create')->withCategories($categories);
```

And in the view :

```
{{ Form::select('categories', $categories) }}
```

Comment: Well, in this format how can I set value as category id ? Is that possible ?

Comment: still same error :(Call to undefined method App\Category::lists())

Comment: I just use pluck method instead lists, it works now. Thank you for all your help :)